# Concatenate Streams or Iterables: StackOverflow

Tags: java, guava, java-stream

Recently on my job I had to process a bunch of xml files sequentially. In this case I wrote a sort of tree walk, so each xml file became an Iterator<SomeXmlElement>.

Later on the program didn't care about which SomeXmlElement object came from which file, so I wanted to concatenate all the Iterators into one.

This is roughly how the concat'ing was done (using String instead of SomeXmlElement):

```java
Stream<String> s = Stream.empty();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  s = Stream.concat(s, Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3").stream());
}
s.findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

It turns out that this never prints anything, it just hangs for a while and eventually you get heap error or stack overflow. So I tried again, this time using guava:

```java
Iterable<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  s = Iterables.concat(s, Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
}
System.out.println(Iterables.getFirst(s, null));
```

Somewhat surprisingly, this also throws a StackOverflow. In the end I had to do the concat'ing manually, by implementing Iterator, and that finally worked as expected.

Why do the concatenate methods of these standard libraries fail when there's enough data? Streams and Iterables are designed to handle even infinite input, after all. Is there an easy alternative, apart from the "hard way" of implementing Iterator?

Comment: Note that the [documentation of `Stream.concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) explicitely warns about this…

Comment: It does, although the warning is a bit vague. It also doesn't give you a clue what to do instead. Guava doesn't have a warning at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate a large number of streams use `flatMap`.  In your example, you would use it like this:

```
Stream<String> s = IntStream.range(0, 100000).boxed()
     .flatMap(i -> Stream.of("1", "2", "3"));
```

For your actual problem, let's say that you have a method with a signature `Stream<SomeXmlElement> parseFile(Path p)` and a `Stream<Path> files` that comes from walking the tree.

Then you can obtain a `Stream<SomeXmlElement>`:

```
Stream<SomeXmlElement> elements = files.flatMap(p -> parseFile(p));
```

Comment: Accepted. There shouldn't be a loop in there, it's the wrong idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can extract a method as below:

```
private <T> Stream<T> flatten(final Collection<T> ... collections) {
    return Stream.of(collections).map(Collection::stream).reduce(Stream::concat).get();
}
```

Returning concatenated stream would be good idea if you require further pipelining. Otherwise you could map and collect the result.

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem, which is that `Stream::concat` cannot be used to merge a large number of streams without blowing up the stack.  If you try to call your `flatten` method on 100000 collections, it will fail with a `StackOverflowError`

Comment: @Misha I am not sure what you said is happening. I was able to flatten 2million objects (object size ~2KB) which were in 500000 collections without any issue. Memory usage was ~2.5GB out of 4GB Heap and ~20MB metaspace (java 1.8_45). The program ran into OOM - GC overhead limit exceed error (not SOE) once I tried to flatten 4-5million objects. Theoretically that's legit because too little GC in my sample program. Did you try running this ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out Lakshitha. I also ran into OOM at first, which is even worse than stack overflow. It crashes the whole JVM, not only one thread, and in a multi threaded program you may have trouble figuring out what's going on. Your program will fail in production, after running fine on smaller test data. There should be a bigger warning sign on the concat method.